# MongoDB+Doctrine: How to sort the query by text search score

Tags: php, mongodb, doctrine, full-text-search

I have a code like this that searches by the text index:

```
$expr = $queryBuilder->expr()->operator('$text', ['$search' => $this->value]);
$result = $queryBuilder->equals($expr)->getQuery()->execute();
```

But the result is not sorted by the relevance, which I want.

I found some info [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/meta/) but could not figure out how to add field score to search result using Doctrine.

I guess it would be easy from there just adding:

```
$queryBuilder->sort('score');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could not find relevant documentation, but I did find [this issue](https://github.com/doctrine/mongodb/issues/152) on the project's Github repo. The issue has a milestone of 1.2.0 release, but it seems it has already been released in the 1.1.x branch. The issue has been closed via [this commit](https://github.com/doctrine/mongodb/commit/d7d10ab26329218d278de297eb9da856f38235d1).

From the commit, it seems that all you need to sort your results by the *textScore* metadata info is one extra method call on the query builder:

```
$result = $queryBuilder
    ->equals($expr)
    ->sortMeta('fieldToSearch', 'textScore') // <- this
    ->getQuery()
    ->execute();
```

Comment: It leaked to 1.1.7 by mistake which was already corrected. So we will unfortunately need to wait for 1.2.0. Thanks anyway.