# Mongodb doctrine query builder full text search does not sort the results based on the textScore

Tags: mongodb, symfony, sorting, full-text-search, doctrine-odm

I am new to doctrine mongodb query builder and trying to combine query builder and mongodb to do a full text search in php(Symfony 2.6) 
first of all I have indexed the field of the collection I want to search in.
and then, in my action I have the query below:

```
$dm = $this->getDoctrineMongoDB()->getManager();
$qb = $dm->createQueryBuilder('MyBundle:MyCollection');
$expr = $qb->expr()->operator('$text', array(
    '$search'   => 'I love stackoverflow',
    '$language' => 'none', // or one of those other languages
    ),
    array('score' => array('$meta' => 'textScore'))
    );
$qb->field(null)->equals($expr->getQuery());
$qb->sort(array('score' => array('$meta' => 'textScore')));
```

This query returns the desired results but it does not sort them. I mean it does not sort the results based on the score of each document that matches with the query. and I have gone through all of the text search and sort documents in mongoDb and stack overflow answers like 
  [php mongodb full-text search and sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23084243/php-mongodb-full-text-search-and-sort) and [MongoDB+Doctrine: How to sort the query by text search score](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30512034/mongodbdoctrine-how-to-sort-the-query-by-text-search-score) but none of them helped me fix this query textScore-based sorting. I really need your help and every bit of your help will be much appreciated.

Comment: and this is how I have indexed my field in the collection ' /** * @MongoDB\Field(type="string") * @MongoDB\Index("title"="text") */ protected $myField; '

Answer (score 1):

Fortunately I found the answer to my question. My doctrine mongodb was old and that`s why query builder did not recognize the method sortMeta() So I upgraded the doctrine/mongodb version 1.0 to the last version 1.2.x-dev and the code below getting from this link 
   [MongoDB+Doctrine: How to sort the query by text search score](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30512034/mongodbdoctrine-how-to-sort-the-query-by-text-search-score) works like a charm .

Comment: $expr = $qb->expr()->operator('$text', array(
  '$search'   =>'I love stackoverflow',
  '$language' => 'none', // or one of those other languages
     )
     );
     
     $qb->sort(array('score' => array('$meta' => 'textScore')));