# Mongo doctrine full text search with textscore is not working

Tags: mongodb, full-text-search, doctrine-odm

I am using doctrine/mongodb version 1.2.0. I want to do full text search and the result should be with textscore.

Since i am using hash variable, not able to create Annotation for textindex. So i did this directly in mongodb database.

The problem is not able to get score value. i couldnt find the score  data in the result set.

Looking for your guidance. Thanks in advance. Find the code below

```
    $qr = $this->createQueryBuilder(); 
    foreach ($configurations as $configuration) {
       if($configuration == 'a'){
         $qr->addAnd($qr->expr()->field($key)->equals("data"));
       }
       else if($configuration == 'b'){
          $qr->addAnd($expr = $qr->expr()->operator('$text',  
         array('$search' =>"string to be search",'$language' => 'en'),
          array('score' => array('$meta' => 'textScore')))
         );
       }
    }
$qr->sort(array('score' => array('$meta' => 'textScore')));
 $result = $qr->getQuery()->getSingleResult();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MongoDB+Doctrine: How to sort the query by text search score](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30512034/mongodbdoctrine-how-to-sort-the-query-by-text-search-score)

Comment: Hi in the link you have mentioned, textscore value is available and problem is not able to sort based on that score. But my problem is textScore value is not available in my result set. Also i have created index in database directly instead of Annotation.

Comment: So, here's the rub. You want to use an ODM with a "strict" idea of what an "object" looks like as a declared "class". Then all of a sudden you want extra fields in the results. You cannot have it both ways. The data is either just either just a "raw" form from MongoDB, where of course you can have additional fields. Or if you expect it to load up magically in your class definitions, then you are out of luck since none of them have a textScore property. So you would therefore only be able to return a "raw" result.

Comment: Oh. Thank you for your answer.